# Excel 2007 VBA find function. Trying to find data between two sheets and put it in a third sheet

Tags: vba, excel-2007

All,

I am trying to write a macro to search all cells from column 2 from Sheet1 in Sheet2 and copy found rows to Sheet 2.

This is what I have got so far:

```
Sub CopyUnique()
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Set QA_14 = Sheets("QA 14Feb")
   Set Prod_14 = Sheets("Prod 14Feb")
   Set Prod_O14 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Counter = 1

   Dim Found As Range
   Dim QARange As Range
   For Row = 1 To Prod_14.UsedRange.Rows.Count

       Set QARange = QA_14.Cells(2, 1)
       Set Found = QARange.Find(What:=Prod_14.Cells(Row, 2).Text, After:=QA_14.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

       If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            Prod_14.UsedRange.Range(Cells(Row, 1), Cells(Row, Prod_14.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Copy Prod_O14.Range("A" & LTrim(Str(Counter)))

            Counter = Counter + 1
       End If

    Next

End Sub
```

The problem occurs on the line with Find function. Just gives a type mismatch error. I have tried splitting all variables to separate line but they're not part of problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The *after* parameter you're using is invalid. Remove it and you won't receive the type mismatch error anymore. First question answered, and now we have other... I'm checking how we can set this value properly.

I believe that maybe if you give a better explanation of what you're trying to achieve we could improve our assistance giving suggestions.

Rgds

Edit:

It seems that the *After* needs to be within the range being searched (and I believe that's not what you want).

This code does not raise errors, although I believe does not do what you want either. If you give us a better example of what you need, we may be able to help you further.

**tip #1:** Next time when submitting code, I'd ask you to also include in your code  the declaration of the variables you're using (you're using *Option Explicit*, right?). Specially in *Type Mismatch* errors, the variable type may cause the problem.

**tip #2:** I'd suggest to take a look on Hungarian Notation.

```
Sub test()

    Dim qa_14 As Worksheet
    Dim prod_14 As Worksheet
    Dim prod_o14 As Worksheet
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim rngAfter As Excel.Range
    Dim rngWhat As Excel.Range

    Dim Found As Range
    Dim QARange As Range

    Set qa_14 = Sheets("QA 14Feb")
    Set prod_14 = Sheets("Prod 14Feb")
    Set prod_o14 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    iCounter = 1

    For iRow = 1 To prod_14.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Set QARange = qa_14.Cells(2, 1)

        Set rngAfter = QARange.Cells(1, 1)

        Set Found = QARange.Find(What:=prod_14.Cells(iRow, 2).Text, After:=rngAfter, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not Found Is Nothing Then

            prod_14.UsedRange.Range(Cells(iRow, 1), Cells(iRow, prod_14.UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Copy prod_o14.Range("A" & LTrim(Str(iCounter)))

            iCounter = iCounter + 1

       End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of that particular problem is that xlText isn't a valid option for lookin.  I believe you need xlValues or xlFormulas.

There are a couple of other things to consider.  Sheet1 is not a good variable name.  Each sheet has a CodeName property that doesn't change when the sheet's tab name changes.  By default, these CodeNames are Sheet1, Sheet2, etc.  It may not cause a problem, but it's probably best to avoid it.

In you For Next, you increment Row by Sheet1.UsedRange.Count, which is a count of the number of cells in the used range.  You should probably use

```
For Row = 1 to Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Edit

Here's another procedure that I think does what you want.

```
Sub CopyUnique()

    Dim shQa14 As Worksheet
    Dim shProd14 As Worksheet
    Dim shProdO14 As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    Set shQa14 = Sheets("QA 14Feb")
    Set shProd14 = Sheets("Prod 14Feb")
    Set shProdO14 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rCell In Intersect(shProd14.UsedRange, shProd14.Columns(2)).Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            Set rFound = shQa14.Cells.Find(rCell.Value, , xlValues, xlPart)

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                Intersect(rFound.EntireRow, rFound.Parent.UsedRange).Copy _
                    shProdO14.Cells(shProdO14.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

I don't specify a lot of the Find parameters, only ones I care about.

Comment: Did all those changes. Doesn't help. Updated the code in original question.