# Excel VBA :: Find function in loop

Tags: excel, vba, macos, find

I'm trying to loop through several worksheets that contain some source data that has to be copied to one main sheet, called "PriorityList" here.
First of all, the sub is not working and I think the error is somewhere in the "**find**"-method. Second, the sub takes quite long to run, and I think this is maybe because the "find"-method searches through the whole sheet instead of only the relevant range?

Thank you very much for your answers!

Patrick

```
Sub PriorityCheck()
'Sub module to actualise the PriorityList

Dim CurrWS As Long, StartWS As Long, EndWS As Long, ScheduleWS As Long
StartWS = Sheets("H_HS").Index
EndWS = Sheets("E_2").Index

Dim SourceCell As Range, Destcell As Range

For CurrWS = StartWS To EndWS

    For Each SourceCell In Worksheets(CurrWS).Range("G4:G73")

        On Error Resume Next

        'Use of the find method
        Set Destcell = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells.Find(What:=SourceCell.Value, After:=Worksheets("PriorityList").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        'Copying relevant data from source sheet to main sheet
        If Destcell <> Nothing Then
            Destcell.Offset(0, 2).Value = SourceCell.Offset(0, 5).Value + Destcell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            If SourceCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "x" Then Destcell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "x"
            End If
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

    Next SourceCell

Next CurrWS

End Sub
```

Comment: BTW I just noticed your `Set Destcell = Worksheets(CurrWS).Cells.Find(What:=SourceCell.Value, After:=Worksheets("PriorityList").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues,...` You are trying to find soureCell value in `PriorityList`?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Did you find an error in that particular line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here short sample how to **use 'Find' method to find the first occurrence of the source.Value in the priorityList**.

**Source cell** is one of the cells from the range *"G4:G73"* and **priorityList** is used range on *"PriorityList"* sheet. Hope this helps.

```
Public Sub PriorityCheck()
    Dim source As Range
    Dim priorityList As Range
    Dim result As Range

    Set priorityList = Worksheets("PriorityList").UsedRange

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Worksheets("H_HS").Index To Worksheets("E_2").Index
        For Each source In Worksheets(i).Range("G4:G73")
            Set result = priorityList.Find(What:=source.Value)
            If (Not result Is Nothing) Then
                ' do stuff with result here ...
                Debug.Print result.Worksheet.Name & ", " & result.Address
            End If
        Next source
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Daniel! Your version does the job really well!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `arrays`. You save each range into an array, then iterate through array to satisfy your if-else condition. BTW IF you want to find the exact line with code error, then you must comment `On Error Resume Next` line.. :) Further, you can simply store the values into a new array, dump everything else into the main sheet later after iterating through all the sheets instead of going back and forth to sheets, code, sheets..code..

```
Dim sourceArray as Variant, priorityArray as Variant
'-- specify the correct priority List range here
'-- if multi-column then use following method
priorityArray = Worksheets(CurrWS).Range("A1:B10").Value
'-- if single column use this method
' priorityArray = WorkSheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets(CurrWS).Range("A1:A10").Value)

For CurrWS = StartWS To EndWS
   On Error Resume Next    
   sourceArray = Worksheets(CurrWS).Range("G4:J73").Value
   For i = Lbound(sourceArray,1) to UBound(sourceArray,1)
     For j = Lbound(priorityArray,1) to UBound(priorityArray,1)
        If Not IsEmpty(vArr(i,1)) Then    '-- use first column
        '-- do your validations here..
        '-- offset(0,3) refers to J column from G column, that means
        '---- sourceArray(i,3)...
        '-- you can either choose to update priority List sheet here or
        '---- you may copy data into a new array which is same size as priorityArray
        '------ as you deem..
        End If
     Next j
   Next i       
Next CurrWS
```

PS: Not front of a MS Excel installed machine to try this out. So treat above as a code un-tested. For the same reason I couldn't run your `find` method. But it seems odd. Don't forget when using `match` or `find` it's important to do proper error handling. Try checking out [`find` based solutions provided here.

- [VBA in find function runtime error 91](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199951/vba-in-find-function-runtime-error-91/9200091#9200091)
- [Excel 2007 VBA find function. Trying to find data between two sheets and put it in a third sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095801/excel-2007-vba-find-function-trying-to-find-data-between-two-sheets-and-put-it)

I have edited the initial code to include the main logic using two array. Since you need to refer to values in `J` column of source sheets, you will need to adjust source array into a two-dimensional array. So you can do the validations using first column and then retrieve data as you desire.

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion using the arrays and I must say it works way faster now! So one problem is resolved!

Comment: But: I discovered that my find function actually never is successful, i.e. `DestCell` is always `Nothing`... Were is the error in that line? I changed it now to `Set Destcell = Worksheets("PriorityList").Cells.Find(What:=vArr(i).Value, After:=Worksheets("PriorityList").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)` Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What is your motive for the `find` method? :) Do you want to search array value in `PriorityList Sheets`? I had the impression you want to find, validate values in other sheets and paste them into `PriorityList` sheet.. please clarify.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry if my question was ambiguous. Basically, I have some pairs of values (strings) in all the sheets I'm looping through and in the main sheet (`PriorityList`). I want to spot the values in the main sheet and then copy some values from the source to the main sheet. I assumed that you need for either case you mentioned the `find`-method?

Comment: As you are copying values from source sheets to PriorityList, can you confirm if your Priority List gets increased as the found/validated-source-data is copied? If your Priority List is just one static range (that doesn't change/increased with new data) you can simply copy PriorityList to another Array(main array) then do the validation of source array vs main Array... then dump the new array that has all the ***found/validated some-values*** to PriorityList

Comment: PriorityList is static, so your method with the main array would work and I think that I see how you would implement it without using the find-method. Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this since I'm not experienced with arrays in VBA. Could you show me one possible implementation of your suggested solution? On the other hand, why does my use of the find-mehtod not work? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, please try this out. You can refer to the posts given to check exact issue of your find method. Without running the code it's hard to say why.. :$ One thing for sure, remove the `on error` statements as mentioned..

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer! I'm gonna try out all your recommendations right now. I apologize for my small delay, too. Unfortunately I was busy yesterday.

Comment: Your version using arrays is probably more sophisticated than the one above looping through the cells. For more complex tasks, I guess I would have to use your version, but for my still rather simple PriorityList, the version using cells is easier to implement and with adding a line like `If Source <> "" Then` that version turned out to work incredibly fast as well. But anyways, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone maybe interested, this is the code version that I finally used (pretty similar to the version suggested by Daniel Dusek):

```
Sub PriorityCheck()
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim PriorityList As Range
    Dim Dest As Range

    Set PriorityList = Worksheets("PriorityList").UsedRange

    Dim i As Long

    For i = Worksheets("H_HS").Index To Worksheets("S_14").Index
        For Each Source In Worksheets(i).Range("G4:G73")
        If Source <> "" Then
            Set Dest = PriorityList.Find(What:=Source.Value)
            If Not Dest Is Nothing Then
                If Dest <> "" Then
                    Dest.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
                    Dest.Offset(0, 2).Value = Source.Offset(0, 5).Value + Dest.Offset(0, 2).Value
                End If
            If Source.Offset(0, 3).Value = "x" Then Dest.Offset(0, 3).Value = "x"
                Debug.Print Dest.Worksheet.Name & ", " & Dest.Address
            End If
        End If
        Next Source
    Next i

    MsgBox "Update Priority List completed!"

End Sub
```